# Sum of hex values in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to input 2 ascii files and output them into 2 hex files (sym.txt ,sym2.txt) and then do the sum of two hex files and output the reverse of the value into a last file (symout.txt).I really don't see what I'm doing wrong ... Thank you for the help in advance :D.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $in, "<", "f1.txt";
my $input = do { local $/; <$in> };

open my $out, ">", "sym.txt";
print $out unpack 'H*', $input;

open my $in1, "<", "f2.txt";
my $input1 = do { local $/; <$in1> };

open my $out1, ">", "sym2.txt";
print $out1 unpack 'H*', $input1;

    open(my $fh1, '<', 'sym.txt') or die $!;
    open(my $fh2, '<', 'sym2.txt') or die $!;
    open my $fh_out, '>', 'symout.txt' or die $!;

   until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {

    my @l1 = map hex, split '', <$fh1>;
    my @l2 = map hex, split '', <$fh2>;

    my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

    my @sum = map {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;

    @sum = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } @sum;

        print { $fh_out } reverse(@sum), "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: i get the 2 files with hex values but my symout.txt output is empty ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you haven't closed `$out` or `$out1`, so the data that has been printed to those handles is still in memory waiting to be flushed

It's best to use lexical file handles (as you are doing) and add blocks so that the handles are closed implicitly when they go out of scope

Here's an example of what I mean. Note that I've also added `use autodie` to avoid having to check the status of every `open` call (which you should have done but didn't!)

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14;
use autodie;

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', 'f1.txt';
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'sym.txt';
    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;
}

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', 'f2.txt';
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'sym2.txt';
    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;
}

open my $fh1, '<', 'sym.txt';
open my $fh2, '<', 'sym2.txt';

until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {

    my @l1 = map hex, split //, <$fh1>;
    my @l2 = map hex, split //, <$fh2>;

    my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

    my @sum = map {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;

    @sum = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } @sum;

    open my $out, '>', 'symout.txt';
    print { $out } reverse(@sum), "\n";
}
```

Comment: The original description is vague, but it worked out pretty well except the newline on the final output did not workout. I will thumb up.

Comment: @Gang: *"The original description is vague"*  Do you mean the OP's description in the question, or my narrative in the solution?

Comment: Borodin, yours is very clear, now looking back, the OP' s description is clear as well, just I was trapped by myself, doing it line by line.